# KDE Neon doesn't detect audio devices from motherboard

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, kde-neon

I recently updated my KDE Neon to 20.04, and audio from the motherboard doesn't get detected.  It does, however, detect the one from the GPU.

```
$ inxi -A
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Family HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP106 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-3: Huawei UVC Camera type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-7634-generic
```

Before running `# alsa force-reload`, `$ pacmd list-cards` only detects 2 audio I/O.

```
$ pacmd list-cards                         
2 card(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 7
        properties:
                alsa.card = "2"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xdf080000 irq 17"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "10de"
                device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
                device.product.id = "10f1"
                device.product.name = "GP106 High Definition Audio Controller"
                device.string = "2"
                device.description = "GP106 High Definition Audio Controller"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        profiles:
                output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
        active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo-extra1>
        sinks:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1/#0: GP106 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
        sources:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor/#0: Monitor of GP106 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
        ports:
                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                device.product.name = "GF276
       "
                hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 1
        name: <alsa_card.usb-Ruision_UVC_Camera_20200416-02>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 8
        properties:
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "UVC Camera"
                alsa.long_card_name = "Ruision UVC Camera at usb-0000:00:14.0-12, high speed"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:12:1.2"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.2/sound/card1"
                udev.id = "usb-Ruision_UVC_Camera_20200416-02"
                device.bus = "usb"
                device.vendor.id = "12d1"
                device.vendor.name = "Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd."
                device.product.id = "4321"
                device.product.name = "UVC Camera"
                device.serial = "Ruision_UVC_Camera_20200416"
                device.form_factor = "webcam"
                device.string = "1"
                device.description = "UVC Camera"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
        profiles:
                input:mono-fallback: Mono Input (priority 1, available: unknown)
                input:multichannel-input: Multichannel Input (priority 1, available: unknown)
                off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
        active profile: <input:mono-fallback>
        sources:
                alsa_input.usb-Ruision_UVC_Camera_20200416-02.mono-fallback/#1: UVC Camera Mono
        ports:
                analog-input: Analog Input (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:

                multichannel-input: Multichannel Input (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
```

And after running `# alsa force-reload`:

```
$ pacmd list-cards      
3 card(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 7
        properties:
                alsa.card = "2"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xdf080000 irq 17"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "10de"
                device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
                device.product.id = "10f1"
                device.product.name = "GP106 High Definition Audio Controller"
                device.string = "2"
                device.description = "GP106 High Definition Audio Controller"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        profiles:
                output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
        active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo-extra1>
        sinks:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1/#0: GP106 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
        sources:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor/#0: Monitor of GP106 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
        ports:
                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                device.product.name = "GF276
       "
                hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 1
        name: <alsa_card.usb-Ruision_UVC_Camera_20200416-02>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 8
        properties:
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "UVC Camera"
                alsa.long_card_name = "Ruision UVC Camera at usb-0000:00:14.0-12, high speed"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:12:1.2"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.2/sound/card1"
                udev.id = "usb-Ruision_UVC_Camera_20200416-02"
                device.bus = "usb"
                device.vendor.id = "12d1"
                device.vendor.name = "Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd."
                device.product.id = "4321"
                device.product.name = "UVC Camera"
                device.serial = "Ruision_UVC_Camera_20200416"
                device.form_factor = "webcam"
                device.string = "1"
                device.description = "UVC Camera"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
        profiles:
                input:mono-fallback: Mono Input (priority 1, available: unknown)
                input:multichannel-input: Multichannel Input (priority 1, available: unknown)
                off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
        active profile: <input:mono-fallback>
        sources:
                alsa_input.usb-Ruision_UVC_Camera_20200416-02.mono-fallback/#1: UVC Camera Mono
        ports:
                analog-input: Analog Input (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:

                multichannel-input: Multichannel Input (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:

    index: 2
        name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 29
        properties:
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf220000 irq 128"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "a170"
                device.product.name = "100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "0"
                device.description = "Built-in Audio"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        profiles:
                input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 65, available: no)
                output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6500, available: no)
                output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6565, available: no)
                output:analog-surround-21: Analog Surround 2.1 Output (priority 1300, available: no)
                output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: no)
                output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Output (priority 1200, available: no)
                output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1265, available: no)
                output:analog-surround-41: Analog Surround 4.1 Output (priority 1300, available: no)
                output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: no)
                output:analog-surround-50: Analog Surround 5.0 Output (priority 1200, available: no)
                output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1265, available: no)
                output:analog-surround-51: Analog Surround 5.1 Output (priority 1300, available: no)
                output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: no)
                output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 5500, available: unknown)
                output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5565, available: no)
                off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
        active profile: <output:iec958-stereo>
        sinks:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo/#1: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)
        sources:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo.monitor/#2: Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)
        ports:
                analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:

                analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:

                analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
                iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
```

Is there a way to fix this so that I don't have to run `# alsa force-reload` every boot?  I can have it autorun, but I'd prefer to have this fixed.

Here's my system info:

- Operating System: KDE neon Testing Edition
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.19.3
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.73.0
- Qt Version: 5.14.2
- Kernel Version: 5.4.0-7634-generic
- OS Type: 64-bit
- Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz
- Memory: 15.6 GiB of RAM
- Graphics Processor: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2
- Motherboard: MSI H170 Gaming M3

Answer (score 0):

After looking around, removing `timidity-daemon` worked.